# Как сделать ссылку в запросе SQL на фреймы с датой?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, pandas, oracle

Как правильно указать промежуток дат?

Пробую так:

```
pr = df456['Дата'].max().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

tdate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


sql = f'''select so."Дата",
                 so."Вес",
                 so."№ дела"                
                                               
        from datamart.PIECE_PROD so
           
             
        where so."Вес" = 'увеличился'
        
        and so."№ дела" = 'доступно'
        and so."Дата" between 'pr' AND 'tdate'
            
   '''
osn_data = pd.DataFrame(mycur.execute(sql).fetchall(), columns=['Дата',
                                                                'Вес',                                                                
                                                                '№ дела'
                                                               ])
                                                        
                                                       
osn_data
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> DatabaseError: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: `and so."Дата" between 'pr' AND 'tdate'` - если Вы полагаете, что передаёте значения переменных в этот фрагмент, таки нет.

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы таки да?

Comment: `and so."Дата" between %s AND %s` и соответственно `mycur.execute(sql, (pr, tdate))`

Comment: *я ведь сюда за помощью, а не за хейтом обращаюсь..* https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - прямо в самом начале пишут "Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа". Вы же явно не озаботились не то, что поискать, но даже просто посмотреть справку по cursor.execute на предмет передачи параметров в запрос.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше воспользуйтесь методом [pd.read_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) и **параметризированным** запросом:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from cx_Oracle import makedsn
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine

usr = "test"
pwd = "my_oracle_password"
dsn = makedsn("ora_scan_or_hostname", 1521, service_name="my_service_name")

engine = create_engine(f'oracle+cx_oracle://{usr}:{pwd}@{dsn}')

qry = f'''select so."Дата",
                 so."Вес",
                 so."№ дела"                                                              
        from datamart.PIECE_PROD so             
        where so."Вес" = 'увеличился'     
        and so."№ дела" = 'доступно'
        and so."Дата" between :d1 AND :d2 '''

d1 = df456['Дата'].max()
d2 = pd.to_datetime("now")

params = (d1, d2)

df = pd.read_sql(qry, engine, params=params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю всех за помощь, дело было в недостаче кавычек и функции TO_TIMESTAMP

```
sql = f'''select so."Дата",
                 so."Вес",
                 so."№ дела"                
                                           
        from datamart.PIECE_PROD so
       
         
        where so."Вес" = 'увеличился'
    
        and so."№ дела" = 'доступно'
        and so."Дата" between TO_TIMESTAMP(''' +"'" +pr+ "','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:mi:ss') 
and TO_TIMESTAMP('"+ tdate+"','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:mi:ss')"
        

osn_data = pd.DataFrame(mycur.execute(sql).fetchall(), columns=['Дата',
                                                                'Вес',                                                                
                                                                '№ дела'
                                                               ])
```

Comment: Так делать ни в коем случае нельзя. Не стоит ответом предлагать решение, которое  хоть и устранило ошибку, но  является крайне неэффиктивным и потенциально опасным. Лучше посмотрите предложенные вам решения в других ответах.  @MaxU ТС не совсем понял ваше решение. Может стоит более явно в ответе указать,  где его ошибка :)